# Div scrolls under fixed image

Tags: css, html

I've got a problem. I've got a fixed image in something what is a header.
I also have a div. The div has to scroll. But it scrolls under the fixed image.

Is there a fix for this problem? Or a workaround??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u could use z-index to decide who can appear in front of one another

Comment: Make sure the element with the z-index has a position property. Z-index only works with positioned elements.